# Matrix similarity along one axis

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, correlation

Hi haves 2D matrices and want to calculate a measure of similarity along the Y axis.

For example, the following matrix should yield 0:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

While this one should yield 1:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

In these examples I used binary values in the matrices, but in reality they are floats between 0 and 1. The matrices are much bigger and there is noise - the calculation has to be very fast as I have a large number of matrices to calculate for every experiment.

Right now I'm doing a Random PCA, keeping the first component as the measure of similarity. However, it is somewhat slow and I have the feeling that it is overkill. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: element wise multiplication will give a measure of similarity.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: sum the rows and you shall get [1,1,1,1] in the first case and [0,4,4,0] in the second case. then you can normalize such as 1 is mapped to 0 and 4 to 1.

Answer (score 3):

The real problem here is how to define *similarity*.

I assume you define similarity as *proportion of equal rows*. That is, if you randomly take two different rows, what is the probability that those two rows are equal? This definition is the simplest I can think of that fits your example desired results.

If that's indeed what you want, it is easily computed as follows, where `A` denotes the data matrix:

```
d = squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(A, [3 2 1])), 2)); %// test all pairs
    %// of rows for equality
result = (sum(d(:))-size(d,1))/(numel(d)-size(d,1)); %// compute average, but
    %// removing similarity of each row with itself
```

Comment: I agree that the definition of similarity is the issue.  Mean count is a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `all` with `axis=0` can have the logical result, then reapply to the matrix:

Example:

```
mx
matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]])

mx1
matrix([[0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

To apply:

```
# use .A to convert to array to do the logical calculation
np.matrix(mx.A * mx.all(axis=0).A)
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The same for mx1:

```
np.matrix(mx1.A * mx1.all(axis=0).A) 
matrix([[0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```